# Is it possible for my friends to find out that I liked a video on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

Who can see that I've "liked" a video? Is liking a video on YouTube private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likes in general are private though can be set public and can be shown on the channel feed on https://youtube.com/account_privacy.

If the person who liked set up the twitter autoshare function for them liking a video and you connected your YouTube channel on twitter, you will receive a tweet saying "I liked a @YouTube video from @`yourtwittername` youtu.be/`VideoID`?a `VideoTitle`"